# About Capturing Result of SMS on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

If I send a message to number `123(or any number that doesn't exist)`.

How to  get the feedback－Send failed via my app?
My device is `JB` and I just use the app to test not for `appstore`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twilio API or some other API for same which will let you know if that phone number can receive SMS or not. You can check it before requesting to send SMS

Link for Twilio are as follows

http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-check-to-see-if-phone-numbers-can-receive-sms